# Using Sope Storage in Android 11 and above to get downloaded file

Tags: android, storage, mediastore, android-11, target-sdk

I have an Android application. It has a download manager to download an APK file (saved inside Download directory) and I want to get and install APK file after it is downloaded. It works properly on Android below 11 but from Android 11 we need to use Scope Storage API instead of getting file from the Environment method. Also, I used Manage External Storage inside it for getting file but Google rejected my app because it says:

"You have requested access to All Files Access permission but it appears that your app’s core feature requires access to only Media Files."

so could you please give me any approach for getting the downloaded file that I downloaded into the Download directory and sending its URI to Android package manager to install?

Comment: You can follow this link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#:~:text=On%20the%20Settings%20%3E%20Privacy%20%3E%20Permission,files%22%20is%20read%2Donly.

Comment: @HalilSahin tnx man, I read your link and I changed my save location to External Cache Directory and it solved my problem.